# Возвращается объект вместо количества элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

допустим есть такой кусок кода

```
<ul id="ul" class="ul" >
 <li ></li >
 <li ></li >
</ul >
```

Используя jquery, хочу узнать, сколько же селекторов li у меня в теге ul,

```
    console.log( $( function () {
                   $('#ul li').length
               } )
);
```

но консоль выдает совсем непонятный для меня 'jQuery.fn.init [document]'.

upd

```
$( function () {
                  console.log( ($('#ul li').length))
               })
```

этот вариант работает правильно.

Comment: `console.log($('#ul li').length);`

Comment: возвращается 0.

Answer (score 1):

Не работает из-за незнания и очепяток.

```
console.log( // Выводим в лог..
  $( // Объект????
    function () { // Функция????
      $('#ul li').length // Что???
    }
  )
);
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
console.info($('#ul li').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="ul">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Точно 0??

А в этом сниппете 2:

```js
console.log($('#ul li').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul" class="ul" >
 <li ></li >
 <li ></li >
</ul >
```

Comment: алерт выдает правильный результат. не могу понять почему в консоле вот "это"

Comment: прошу меня извинить. console.log нужно писать внутри jquery функции, тогда он выполнится правильно.

Comment: @андрейпупкин эта обертка не нужна, если только не хотите изолировать область сидимости

Comment: без обертки если писать в новом документе результат 0. http://prntscr.com/ogfq4h вот скрин с консолью

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, нужна, `$(function(){...})` - Это аналог `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

Comment: _А в этом сниппете 2:_ - потому что в этом сниппете скрипт физически вставляется **перед закрывающим тегом body**, когда элементы уже присутствуют в dom

Comment: @Grundy да, я и забыл что так тоже люди еще пишут

Answer (score -1):

```js
var i = 0;
$(".ul li").each(function(){
  i++;
});
console.log(i);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul" class="ul" >
 <li ></li >
 <li ></li >
</ul >
```

Вот ещё вариант)

Comment: Как вариант, да, с меня лайк :D